# Worm Gear and Worm Shaft for 2 axis

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

Can a worm gear be used for linear motion as well as for rotation?

To be more specific. Suppose I want the worm gear to rotate as well as move forward, is it possible to achieve that ?

[image: worm gear]

Comment: So, are you trying to use a worm gear setup like a rack and pinion?

Comment: Opposite actually.

Comment: So, what's the input and what's the output. Can you provide a diagram?

Comment: Yo want the worm gear to do a screw motion? If you attached it on some guides forcing the screw motion you should be set.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, this is the opposite of the desired behavior of zoom lenses.  Optics design houses go to some lengths with cams and retainers to allow the lens to extend without rotation.  You might try looking up old (1970s) zoom lens mechanical patents to see if there's anything there you could use.

But as to pure worm gears, since the worm only rotates if it's constrained from translating, you'd need some "secondary" worm that translated the "primary" worm at half the drive gear's linear rate.  Even then I would be concerned that the tiniest error in step-down rate would cause catastrophic lockup.

Comment: Exactly my need. I am trying to design a worm gear that locks onto a retaining ring- rotate it - move the lens - lock it - and pull back the gear which is basically linear motion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is feasible. A bistable locking arrangement need to be added and you can achieve desired functionality.